# Управляющий "Детского мира" или "Детским миром"?

Tags: падежи, грамотная-речь

Как правильно: Управляющий "Детского мира" или Управляющий "Детским миром"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если рассуждать по аналогии со словом "заведующий", сошлюсь на грамоту.ру:

> Слово заведующий (заведующая) управляет тв. п.: заведующий (заведующая) чем — заведующий, заведующая кафедрой, базой, складом, отделом, сектором, производством, редакцией, кадрами, клубом, лабораторией, магазином, фермой, хозяйством, гаражом. Оно сохраняет глагольное управление, ср.: заведовать (кем-чем?) кафедрой.

Т. е. **правильнее** будет "управляющий "Детским миром".

Answer (score 1):

От смысла может зависеть. Управляющий "Детским миром" - это тот, кто им, миром, управляет. Ни больше, ни меньше. Сейчас крайне редко подобное услышишь. 
А управляющий "Детского мира" - просто некая должность, управлять там он может хоть двумя уборщицами и погрузочной тележкой. Сейчас такое не редкость.

Аналогия с "заведующий" не совсем уместна, тем более с глаголом заведовать.

Answer (score 1):

**Оба выражения:** управляющий "Детским миром" или управляющий "Детского мира" ― **звучат немного странно.**

«Детский мир» ― крупнейшая российская сеть магазинов товаров для детей, управляет такой сетью **генеральный директор**.

**Управляющий магазином (Т.п.)**  ― это штатная должность, связанная  с  управлением  конкретным филиалом (надо указывать его  название),  **входящего в эту  сеть**, а в самих магазинах могут быть управляющие отделами.

Поэтому скорее всего речь идет о том, что кто-то работает управляющим (на должности управляющего) **в "Детском мире"**, то есть в сети "Детский мир".

Пример:

Главный герой Джеймс Уормолд ― ничем не примечательный англичанин за сорок, скромный **управляющий магазина пылесосов**, разведен, воспитывает шестнадцатилетнюю красавицу-дочь.

**О какой должности здесь идет речь?** Правильно считать, что это управляющий отделом в магазине, но если это управляющий директор, то  надо бы использовать форму "управляющий магазином".

Comment: Сеть-то она сеть. Но есть и конкретные точки с сетевым названием. И у этой точки есть (могут быть) должности управляющих.

Comment: В разговорном варианте, когда собеседникам ясно, о какой точке идет речь, лучше сказать так: директор  "Детского мира". Потому что слово "управляющий" - это точный термин, штатная должность, то есть деловой стиль. И получается, что  управляющий "Детским миром" или управляющий  "Детского мира" - это микс из  разговорной и деловой речи, к тому же не всегда ясного содержания.